# Solidity ParserError: Expected elementary type name for mapping key type

Tags: solidity

I am unable to process ahead as I am getting the below error. It would be great if someone can help.

```
//add here the mappings
mapping (msg.sender => borrower) public msg.sender;
```

Error - ParserError: Expected elementary type name for mapping key type (msg.sender)

Comment: Cannot use variable instead of data type. What is the goal you're trying to achieve with the mapping?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I intend to develop a solidity code that will allow me to transfer ether from one account to another.